# How to make SOAP calls using SOAP WSDL in Koa.js?

Tags: soap, koa, koa2

In Koa.js how can we consume a SOAP XML web service? Provided the SOAP WSDL is available. I'm using the Koa.js 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handled it.

```
const request = require("request");
```

The use the request in the following way.

```
request(
        url,
        {
            method: "POST",
            /*headers: { //IF REQUIRED
                soapaction: "myActionName"
            },*/
            body: str
        },
        function() {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    );
```